# Can Bluetooth HC-05 Module detect other modules and relay data back to phone?

Tags: bluetooth, hc-05

I want the following to happen:

1. The HC-05 is paired to a phone. The module is called "Amy". The module is worn, say, as a wristband by a person.
2. Amy passes another wristband-with-HC-05-module called "Bob".
3. Amy inquires about Bob, and if the RSSI signal received is strong, it relays the name "Bob" to the phone which will somehow store the information in an app.
4. The HC-05 will pass many other modules, each with different usernames. A list of names will be stored by the phone app.
5. All other HC-05 modules, i.e. Bob and co. , would be doing the same thing with their own phones.

How feasible is this?

Comment: From your last question I thought you wanted to go with BLE beacon.  Why now normal old bluetooth?

Comment: @chrisl I didn't realise that the HC-05 wasn't a BLE device. I am still researching things, and my choice of module isn't set in stone - I am still looking for better options. All I am interested in regarding this question is whether the module can be paired to a phone, but still collect information from inquiring into other nearby devices. I assume the answer would be the same for both Bluetooth and BLE? (Also both Bluetooth and BLE modules can provide an RSSI value, which is the important thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction - BLE devices give off RSSI, but not Bluetooth. BLE devices can be used as iBeacons. I have settled on the HM-19 Bluetooth 5.0 module. A phone acts as an iBeacon scanner.